# how to enforces strict type for laravel jobs?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use declare(strict_types=1); in PHP to force strict typing to be true. However, when I use Laravel jobs, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Jobs\Test;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class TestJob
{
    use Dispatchable;
    public function __construct(private readonly int $number1)
    {
        var_dump($number1);
        die();
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
    }
}
```

When I execute the method `TestJob::dispatch(true);`, the result is:

`int(1)`

But I think PHP should throw an exception because the parameter is not of the stipulated type.

How to enforce strict typing for Laravel jobs?
I'm using php 8.1 and laravel 10

I tried it with a normal class, and strict typing works perfectly. The problem seems to be with Laravel jobs.

Comment: I would recommend against using `strict_types`, because if you have to do it, using types everywhere, then you have a bigger problem... After working more than 6 years with Larave, I never had to use it, and when you do, it is sometimes a code smell that there is something wrong somewhere else... so, remove it 100%.

Comment: Now, related to your question so you don't get mad at me, it is as easy as looking at what `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable` is doing when you call [`::dispatch(value)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5e8f9b0249e9a0b67d674621f7047c4e7eaf9e00/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/Dispatchable.php#L11-L20). You can see that it is using creating a new instance from `PendingDispatch`, but uses `new static`, that means it `new TestJob`. So, the error would be on the file using `TestJob::dispatch`, you have to put stict type in there... but again, if you have to use it, something else is ❌

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead use static dispatch directly, you need to use

```
$job = new TestJob(true);
```

And the last, you can try put `declare(strict_types=1);` on the first line of code in the file that you called the job.  An example if call the job in routes/web.php, you need to put on the first line of routes/web.php. If you call it on the controller, you should put it `declare(strict_types=1);` in the controller also.

But you should consider the matiaslauriti's comment.